# How to set a dynamic string value using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, webkit, css, transform

I have this code but since I use "" the `a.innerheight` does not get replaced by its value. Is it possible to make this dynamic?

```
a.style.webkitTransform = "translate(0,a.innerHeight)"
```

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure what you're asking for... this maybe?

```
a.style.webkitTransform = "translate(0," + a.innerHeight + ")";
```