# How to set a dynamic CSS value with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, height

I want to have responsive padding for a `div` on my page. 
It should be a fifth of the `height` of itself, which is in the variable `cover_height`.

This is my approach so far, which is following an answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/795122/how-to-set-a-dynamic-string-value-using-javascript),
but it doesn't change `padding-top`:

```
var cover = document.getElementById("cover");
var cover_height = cover.height;    

cover.style["padding-top"] = cover_height / 5 + "px";
```

Any feedback regarding the code is welcome as I am pretty new to JS.

Comment: it was before I changed it for this question..but I forgot to add `document.` in front of it..will edit. sorry for the confusion.

Comment: try cover.style.paddingTop = cover_height / 5 + "px";

Comment: (cover_height / 5) + "px";

Comment: By the way JS has no `.height` as far as I know. It should be `clientHeight` (or `style.height` if height is set via inline styles). Other than that I see no other errors.

Comment: `clientHeight` did the trick!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JavaScript (vanilla) has no `element.height` function as far as I know. It should be [`.clientHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientHeight) or [`.offsetHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetHeight) depending on what you are looking for. `offsetHeight` returns the height  including the border, padding and scroll bars.

```js
var cover = document.getElementById("cover");
var cover_height = cover.clientHeight;

cover.style["padding-top"] = cover_height / 5 + "px";
```

```css
#cover {
  height: 300px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id='cover'></div>
```

---

**Does this approach to responsive design make sense?**

If you could use fixed viewport unit based value for `height` then I would recommend something like in the below snippet. Here the height of the element increases (or decreases) based on the height of the viewport and the `padding-top` is always 1/5th of the height. For example, if viewport height is 100px, the element's height would be 30px and the padding top would be 6px.

```css
#cover {
  height: 30vh;
  background: red;
  padding-top: 6vh;
}
```

```html
<div id='cover'></div>
```

If you cannot use viewport units (or) the element's height is auto and will increase or decrease based on content then your approach is reasonably good for setting `padding-top`.

If you had wanted to set `padding-top` based on the width of the element's parent then I would have recommended doing it with pure CSS using percentage values. [This is because a percentage value for `padding` or `margin` is always computed with respect to the element's width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11003911/why-are-margin-padding-percentages-in-css-always-calculated-against-width). An exampe of this behavior is available [here](https://jsfiddle.net/p2mc582j/).

Comment: Thank you, Harry. This does what I want!

Comment: If I may ask: Is this approach to generate a responsive design making sense?

Comment: @Flip: If you were looking to set padding based on width of the element, I'd have recommended pure CSS because that's how percentage values for padding work by default. But for height, I think your approach is reasonably good. Let me think a bit more.

Answer (score 3):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/daxqnap9/1/)**

You should use `clientHeight` or `offsetHeight` instead of `height`.

- **`clientHeight`** : includes the height and vertical padding.
- **`offsetHeight`** : includes the height, vertical padding, and vertical borders.

Example :

```
var cover = document.getElementById("cover");
var cover_height = cover.clientHeight;    
//OR
var cover_height = cover.offsetHeight;    

cover.style.paddingTop = cover_height / 5 + "px";
```

Hope this helps.

---

```js
var cover = document.getElementById("cover");
var cover_height = cover.clientHeight;    

cover.style.paddingTop = cover_height / 5 + "px";
```

```css
#cover{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='cover'> Cover </div>
```